# 20 Questions Game

Tags: c++, if-statement, visual-studio-2013

I've been given the assignment to write a code in C++ where the user has to guess a number between 1-100 and then the computer has 20 questions to try and guess that number. Here is the code that I have written:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int imax; 
char ans;
int imin;
int i;
const char y = 'y';
const char n = 'n';



imax = 100;
imin = 0;
i = 0;
int e = (imax - imin) / 2;

cout << "Think of a number between 1-100." << endl; 

do
{
    cout << "Is the number equal or greater too " << e << endl;
    cin >> ans;
    if (ans == y)
    {
        cout << "Is the number " << e << endl;
        cin >> ans;
        if (ans == y)
        {
            i = e;
            return i;
        }
        else
        {
            imin = e;

        }           
    }
    else
    {
        imax = e;
    }

} while (i == 0);



cout << "Your number is "<< i << endl;

system("PAUSE");

return 0;
}
```

The code works up until it reaches the second if statement. It will accept a 'y' and ask if the number is e, but if 'n' is answered it will not change the imin too e. Also if 'n' is answered for the first if statement it will not set imax to be equal too e. I have been struggling with this for quite some time and would really appreciate any help given.

Comment: It does change imin, it changes it to e, which is unchanged if 'n' is answered. What is the imin supposed to be changed to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EE 273 is a nightmare. I found this code elsewhere:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_VALUE = 100;
const int MIN_VALUE = 1;

int guess;
int high = MAX_VALUE;
int low = MIN_VALUE;

char choice;

int main(){


cout<<"Think about a number between "<<MIN_VALUE<<" and "<<MAX_VALUE<<". \n\n";
guess = ( high-low ) / 2;

while((high-low)!=1){
cout<<"Is your number less than or equal to "<<guess<<"? \nEnter y or n. \n\n";
cin>>choice;

if(choice=='y' || choice=='Y') {
    high = guess;
    guess -= ( high - low ) / 2;
}
else if(choice=='n' || choice=='N') {
    low = guess;
    guess += (high - low ) /2;
}
else cout<<"Incorrect choice."<<endl;


}
cout<<"Your number is: "<<high<<".\n";

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know I have been struggling with it. Thank you good too see different way around the problem.

Comment: Where did you get it? You need to give credit to the author.

Answer (score 2):

You are not changing value of `e` inside **loop** that's why it's do nothing in `else` condition. Also your logic is slightly wrong.
Try this, hopefully this will help:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int imax; 
char ans;
int imin;
int i;
const char y = 'y';
const char n = 'n';



imax = 100;
imin = 0;
i = 0;

cout << "Think of a number between 1-100." << endl; 

do
{
    int e = imin + ((imax - imin) / 2);
    cout << "Is the number equal or greater too " << e << endl;
    cin >> ans;
    if (ans == y)
    {
        cout << "Is the number " << e << endl;
        cin >> ans;
        if (ans == y)
        {
            i = e;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            imin = e;

        }           
    }
    else
    {
        imax = e;
    }

} while (i == 0);



cout << "Your number is "<< i << endl;

system("PAUSE");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `return i;` should be replaced with `break;`

Comment: Thanks for pointed it out.. Changed..